# fill_null in LazyFrame equivalent to strategy on DataFrames

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I've been trying to use `Lazyframe`s instead of `Dataframe`s more often due to performance reasons. Unfortunately, not all features available in `DataFrame`s are available for `LazyFrame`s, one of these being the `.fill_null` method, that takes a `FillNullStrategy` in the `DataFrame`'s method, but simply a generic `E` where `E: Into<Expr>`.

Today, I've tried extensively to replicate the same behavior of using a `FillNullStrategy` for `LazyFrame` to no avail with something like this:

```
lf.fill_null(
            when(col("*").is_null())
                .then(col("*").shift(Some(1)))
                .otherwise(col(name)),
        )
```

That didn't work when `.collect()`ing the `LazyFrame`, though.
I've noticed that we have such feature in `Polars` `Python` ([docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.fill_null.html)), but not for `Rust`. As I assume Polars team wouldn't expose such functionality simply by `.collect()`ing the `LazyFrame` and then `.lazy()`ing it back, I believe I am missing something simpler here.

Does anybody have an insight on this?

Comment: It looks like [`lf.fill_null` ends up calling `lf.select(pl.all().fill_null())`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/lazyframe/frame.py#L3938) which calls [`fill_null_with_strategy`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/src/expr/general.rs#L291) - which I guess is calling [`Series.fill_null`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/series/struct.Series.html#method.fill_null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a little digging, but it looks like the Python version also exposes explicit methods for some fill strategies. It looks like these are also exposed in the Rust APIs. Here's the code for documentation: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/275178c25b4bebf2f2c8a88993d445b5aabc8cc9/polars/polars-lazy/polars-plan/src/dsl/mod.rs#L782

Here's an example of the 'backwards' strategy:

```
let df = DataFrame::new(vec![
    Series::new("data", vec![Some(1.0), None, Some(3.0), Some(4.0)])
])
.unwrap();

let lf = df.lazy().fill_null(col("*").backward_fill(Some(1))).collect();

println!("{:?}", lf);
```

and the result:

```
Ok(shape: (4, 1)
┌──────┐
│ data │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ 1.0  │
│ 3.0  │
│ 3.0  │
│ 4.0  │
└──────┘)
```

There is also a `forward_fill` method available. For setting literal values, you can simply use `col("*").lit(value)`, similarly if you wanted to do max, min, etc, you can use `col("*").max()` (or `.min()`, etc).

If you want to use `fill_null` directly, passing in a `FillNullStrategy`, as mentioned by jqurious that is available on `Series` rather than on DataFrames or Expr. But it looks like you can accomplish most if not all of the strategies  using the above approaches.